# how to make a normalization[code not the theory]

Tags: sql, normalization

where can i find a good normalization tutorial? i already google it but i only find the concept witch i do understand, what i need to know is how to get repeated data from a existing table, to normalized tables with out typing it...example:

```
+-----------------------+
| ID | TEXT | TAGS      |
+-----------------------+
| 1  | text1| repeating |
| 2  | text2| repeating |
+-----------------------+
```

how to normalization would be use 3 tables ,one for tags_id and tags, and another relating the tags_id to ID from the table above...but how does the code already know there is a tag called repeating and dont duplicate it on the another table? i want to get a unormalized table and normalize it .-. can anyone point me a code example for a normalization?

Comment: do you know about unique indexes?

Comment: What is the code that you don't understand?

Comment: index... not realy .-. felling kinda dumb

Comment: I suggest you go through this course, it might help to clarify the matters :) https://www.coursera.org/course/db

Comment: thank you , but it says "no sessions avaliable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite this question should be closed as too broad, here is short manual:

1st You have de-normalized table:

```
original_table
id|text |tags
 1|text1|tag1,tag2...
 2|text2|tag2,tag3...
```

2nd You need to create new, normalized, structure:

```
texts
text_id|text

tags
tag_id(autoincrement)|tag

text_tags
text_id|tag_id
```

3rd Now you need to convert data from old table into new tables (pseudo code):

```
$all_rows = select * from original_table

foreach $row in $all_rows
{
    $text_id = $row.id;
    $text = $row.text;
    $tags_array = split($row.tags, ',');

    insert into texts(text_id, test) values($text_id, '$text');

    foreach $tag in $tags_array
    {
        $tag_id = select tag_id from tags where tag='$tag';
        if $tag_id found
        {
            insert into text_tags(text_id, tag_id) values($text_id, $tag_id);
        }
        else
        {
            insert into tags(tag) values('$tag');
            $tag_id = select last_inserted_id;

            insert into text_tags(text_id, tag_id) values($text_id, $tag_id);
        }
    }
}
```

4th You're done

Comment: thanks :) your phpish code helped a lot